# Script to remove whitespace from RNN generated text before writing to file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am new to working exclusively in the terminal and I'm a bit stuck. I'm using a neural network to generate samples of text, and I want to remove all new line characters and carriage returns from each sample. I want to then write the samples to a text file.

So far I have this to write 100 samples to a file, but I just can't seem to figure out how to remove the new line characters and carriage returns from each sample before they're written to the file.

`for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)) ; do th sample.lua -checkpoint cv/checkpoint_10000.t7 -length 93 -gpu -1 >> sample.txt ; done`

Essentially I have some samples that have carriage returns in the middle of them and just want to get each sample on its own single line. Best approach?

EDIT: this works!

`for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)) ; do th sample.lua -checkpoint cv/checkpoint_10000.t7 -length 93 -sample 1 -gpu -1 | tr -d "\r\t\n" | sed 's/./&\n/93' >> sample.txt ; done`

Comment: If that code is `bash`,  then there are typos here: `; >> sample.txt ; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably via `tr`:

```
tr '\n\r' ' ' < intput-file > output-file
```

Comment: Can you explain this syntax? I don't have an input file. The neural network is generating the text samples and they're not coming from a file.

Comment: @Daina ha. agc beat me to it. `tr` takes two arguments, one set of characters and another set of characters. `tr` "translates" the first set of chars into the second set. In your case, you want to remove all new lines (new line means, '\n', '\r\n', or '\r', on different platforms). Hence, the script replaces all new lines with white spaces. "|" in agc's answer is called "pipe" on Unix. It treats the left-hand side as if it was an input. ">" is called redirection. The output of `tr` is printed directly on the terminal by default. By using ">", you are "redirecting" the output to specified file

Comment: You might want to use `tr -s '\r\n' ' '` to "squeeze" together runs of return/newline characters into single spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
for ((i=1;i<=10000;i++)) ; do 
    th sample.lua -checkpoint cv/checkpoint_10000.t7 -length 93  | tr `\n\r' ' ' 
    echo
done > sample.txt
```

(`tr` code stolen from [realharry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47383028/6136214).)